# php not uploading file in temp directory more than 7 MB

Tags: php, windows, iis-7.5

i have  a php script which should upload files upto 1GB to server. i am running an windows based server with iis 7.5 installed in it.

i have changed my max upload size to 2 GB, post size is greater than the max upload size and all the required things have been changed.

when i am running the script locally it is working file,

when i uploads the script to server and runs it on server (as i have remote connection to that server) it is working fine but when i tries to run the same script from my browser it fails after 100%.

one more thing that the size of the temp file is not increasing after 7889 KB

### and i am getting this error.

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: Have you checked that your max upload size change actually took effect? Get phpinfo() and make sure.

Comment: Just checking: by 'upload', you mean you are using a web-based upload control, right?

Comment: yes i have checked my php info file upload_max_filesize = 40000G(local value) 1000M(master value) & max_file_uploads = 20(both master and local).

Comment: OK, check your Apache log to see what the server error is, and add that to your question.

Comment: Also, numbers like 40000G are crazy, and PHP may not work well with them. Try something sensible like `upload_max_filesize = 2G` (even that is too large for a file upload IMO, but it will at least work).

Comment: ok met me set all those limits to 1G

Comment: i have changed the all the values to 1G and max post to 1.01G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [`memory-limit`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit), it used to default to 8MB in old versions of PHP (before 5.2).

Comment: memory_limit local value = 5000G master value = 1000M

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the php max execution time?